# How to find out if variable is structure or scalar?

Tags: abap

Right now I'm working on one ABAP report where the user puts name of his ABAP report and my report should check naming convention.

Basically it's coding guidelines check.

In my team there is naming convention which says for example that `DATA: table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli` is wrong, correct form should be `DATA: lt_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli`.

I know that in this specific case I can put `lt_` before variable name because there is `TYPE STANDARD TABLE`.

Here is short code how I'm solving this.

[image: Source code]

[image: Output]

What I'm doing is that I read source code into table of string then I'm looping in that table with source code and I have condition that if line contains string `DATA TEXT_TAB TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF` or `LIKE TABLE OF` etc. then SPLIT that line into 3 variables; first will contain `DATA`, second will contain `TEXT_TAB` (basically name of variable) and third will contain the rest of the data declaration `LIKE TABLE OF`. Then I add prefix and table row and concatenate all together `DATA LT_TEXT_TABLE LIKE TABLE OF TEXT`. "It's not stupid if it works" :D

Now I have problem when it comes to variables. For example:

```
DATA: variable01 TYPE string,
      variable02 TYPE spfli.
```

They look same but one is variable and another one is structure/workarea.

My question is ... How to find out if following variable is structure or variable ?

I know there is class `cl_abap_typedescr` with method but it doesn't work with `READ REPORT`.

More info... I have my testing report

```
REPORT ZMH_TEST_SOURCE_CODE.


DATA string01 TYPE string.
DATA: string02 TYPE string,
      string03 TYPE string.
data class04 TYPE REF TO ZMH_CR_CL_SPPM.
data class05 LIKE class04.
DATA: class06 TYPE REF TO ZMH_CR_CL_SPPM.
DATA: table07 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli,
      table08 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli,
      table09 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli,
      table10 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli.
DATA: lt_table11 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli,
      lt_table12 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF spfli.
DATA structure13 LIKE LINE OF table07.
data structure14 LIKE REF TO class05.


CONSTANTS constant15 TYPE i VALUE '13'.
CONSTANTS: constant16 TYPE i VALUE '14'.
DATA text(10) TYPE c.
DATA text_tab LIKE TABLE OF text.
```

And so far my output of report for naming convention

```
Row:30 DATA LT_TEXT_TAB LIKE TABLE OF TEXT.
Row:17 DATA: LT_TABLE07 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF SPFLI,
Row:18 LT_TABLE08 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF SPFLI,
Row:19 LT_TABLE09 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF SPFLI,
Row:20 LT_TABLE10 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF SPFLI.
Row:24 DATA LO_STRUCTURE14 LIKE REF TO CLASS05.
Row:14 DATA LO_CLASS04 TYPE REF TO ZMH_CR_CL_SPPM.
Row:16 DATA: LO_CLASS06 TYPE REF TO ZMH_CR_CL_SPPM.
Row:27  CONSTANTS LC_CONSTANT15 TYPE I VALUE '13'.
Row:28  CONSTANTS: LC_CONSTANT16 TYPE I VALUE '14'.
Row:23 DATA WA_STRUCTURE13 LIKE LINE OF TABLE07.
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have the name of the structure/variable in a field? You can make a select on table DD02L (it contains the DB tables and the structures), if there is an entry than you have a structure, if not, than it is a variable.

Comment: Yes, true ... Like you said before "if there is an entry than you have a structure, if not, than it is a variable." But what if i have some local structure in my report ? TYPES: BEGIN OF structure,
       date TYPE sy-datum,
       END OF structure.
DATA workarea TYPE structure.

Comment: You are right, I have not considered that. I assume there is a naming convention for the local/global types (like lty_ or gty_ or ty_ etc). You can check if the name starts like that. On the other hand, when checking the code you can keep track of the declared TYPEs.

Comment: Do you really need to reinvent the standard SAP Code Inspector naming convention check?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Post code as text instead.

Comment: Yes @JózsefSzikszai this would only work if name starts like that (lt_,lo_,lv_ ect.). But my report should add this prefix before variable name." Naming conventions – data definition: check names of variables, structures, tables (internal, database), types, events, etc if the prefixes are created based on prefix rules. If prefixes are not created add them before name" SandraRossi I'm not sure If code inspector is right tool for this, but i might be wrong. Jagger yes sorry, next time, i will post source code instead

Comment: If you just need that the "report should check naming convention", then **Code Inspector** has already this check. If you want something a little be different, just reuse or enhance the standard code, that will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Agree with Sandra, you are reinventing the wheel, use [own-developed SCI checks](https://blogs.sap.com/2006/11/02/code-inspector-how-to-create-a-new-check/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is too deep for shallow string processing. Add [SCAN ABAP-SOURCE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapscan.htm) to the picture to get more information on what the individual tokens in your statements mean.